# How can I register a new file type association (MP3) for my app?

Tags: android

This is my Main Activity Java file. It does not run on my app, but rather opens with Windows Media Player, because I chose the 'Open With Associated Application option'.

What do I do in order tho solve the problem?

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.android.musicplayer;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.praise);

        Button playButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play_button);

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        Button pauseButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.puase_button);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What file type are you trying to activate with the Media Player?

Comment: I am trying to activate a wav and mp3 file from the raw folder, I cant move from there and still have the Register New File Type Association window open.

Comment: And again what files do I associate wav files with, I have created a raw folder in the res like some others said but it pop up this window of new file type association. WHAT DO I DO?